# Why do I get the Net::SFTP::Foreign error 37, connection broken when running as cron task?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that uses [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign) and it runs just fine if I run it manually. When setup as a cron task, the scripts launches, but fails with an error 37, connection broken. I don't understand why. Does anyone know how I can find out exactly why the connection fails?

Here is where I create:

```
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$source_machine_user_id\@$source_machine_ip",
                                autodie => 1, key_path => $id_file_path,
                                fs_encoding => 'latin1');
```

I've used `more => 'v'`, but I don't get any more information than without it. I've also tried `autodie => 0`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

I'm using public keys for authentication.

Comment: Does your cron user have access right  to `key_path` ?

Comment: Yes, the user has access to the key. The script is set to run under the same user that owns the key. I can execute this script from the command line as that user and it works just fine.

Comment: and does your `key_path` use some relative or absolute path?

Comment: Absolute paths. I've added $Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = 1; Here is the output: 2 (10380) [07:21:55 20120426] #  queueing msg len: 5, code:1, id:3 ... [1]
3 (10380) [07:21:55 20120426] #  waiting for message... [1]
4 (10380) [07:21:55 20120426] SSH connection failed: 37. Doesn't really tell me anything I don't already know.                        What I'm looking for is a way to get more info about the failure. Does anyone know of a way to get more verbose debugging output?

Comment: hum weird, try to pass a `timeout` value.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when `ssh` is not on your cron `$PATH`.

Hard code the `ssh` location on you script using the `ssh_cmd` constructor option. For instance:

```
$s = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, ssh_cmd => '/opt/openssh/bin/ssh', ...);
```

Comment: Nice thought, but I get the same error. $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$source_machine_user_id\@$source_machine_ip", autodie => 0, key_path => $id_file_path, fs_encoding => 'latin1', more => '-v', ssh_cmd => '/usr/bin/ssh'); I also echo'd the path from the script, and it came up as /usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin. ssh is located at /usr/bin/ssh

Comment: Then, activate debugging fully: `$Net::SFTP::Foreign::debug = -1`

Comment: Full debugging on:  _queue_msg:  queueing msg len: 5, code:1, id:3 ... [1]                       
| .........
_get_msg:  waiting for message... [1]
_do_io:  _do_io connected: 1
_do_io:  _do_io select(-,-,-, undef)
_do_io:  _do_io write queue: 9, syswrite: 9, max: 65536, $!:
| .........
_do_io:  _do_io select(-,-,-, undef)
_do_io:  _do_io read sysread: 0, total read: 0, $!:
_conn_lost:  _conn_lost
_set_status:  _set_status code: 7, str: Connection lost
_set_error:  _set_err code: 37, str: Connection to remote server is broken
_conn_lost:  _conn_lost
SSH connection failed: 37

Comment: This is all very cryptic, but it looks the connection is established, but is then dropped. Can anyone else make any sense of this?

Comment: @user675712: what do you get when you run ssh in verbose mode? `Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(..., more => '-vvv')`

Comment: Try also running the script with `strace -f`

Comment: With more => '-vvv' I get the same output as before. 1 (10736) [09:07:52 20120426] SSH connection failed: 37

Comment: Using strace, I get this: "Permission denied (publickey,pas"..., 62) = 62. So it seems that the key is being rejected. At least now I have something work with.

Comment: Where does this `SSH connection failed: 37` thing comes from? Net::SFTP::Foreign or openssh do not generate it. Which version of `ssh` are you using?. Also, you have not activated full debugging on the module, notice you should not set `$...debug` to `1` but to **`-1`**